# Test statistic for regression analysis with robust standard errors

Tags: r, multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity, f-test, robust-standard-error

I am looking for the test statistic for a regression analysis (using lm in R) with robust standard errors. As far as I understood the F-statistic from the original model is invalid but I was wondering if and how I can get test-statistic for the new model.

To get the robust standard errors I used the following code:
coeftest(model1, vcov=vcovHC(model1, type="HC0")) from the sandwich package. But there is no test statistic for the overall signficance for the model as for my original model.